# summing up Oracle PIVOT values

Tags: sql, oracle

below query works to get data rolled up for next 18 months, but to add the total at the end, any easy way?

```
select  *  from 
 ( select A,B 
 months_between(trunc(start_Dt, 'MM'), trunc(sysdate,'MM' )  ) as month_offset,
  qty from total_Table
 where trunc(start_Dt) >= (SELECT trunc(sysdate) - (to_number(to_char(sysdate,'DD')) - 1) FROM dual  ))
  pivot(sum( qty) as sum_quantity for
  month_offset in ( 1,2, 3, 4 )
  order by A, B;
```

Result

```
A B    1    2   3   4   total
A1 B1  100 200 300 400  1000 
A2 B2   50 100 150 200   500 

 select  *  from 
 ( select A,B 
 months_between(trunc(start_Dt, 'MM'), trunc(sysdate,'MM' )  ) as month_offset,
  qty from total_Table
 where trunc(start_Dt) >= (SELECT trunc(sysdate) - (to_number(to_char(sysdate,'DD')) - 1) FROM dual  ))
  pivot(sum( qty) as sum_quantity for
  month_offset in ( 1,2, 3, 4 )
  order by A, B;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation as following, obviously pivot needs some more efforts than conditional aggregation.

```
Select A, B,
SUM(CASE WHEN month_offset = 1 THEN QTY END) AS "1",
SUM(CASE WHEN month_offset = 2 THEN QTY END) AS "2",
SUM(CASE WHEN month_offset = 3 THEN QTY END) AS "3",
SUM(CASE WHEN month_offset = 4 THEN QTY END) AS "4",
SUM(QTY) AS TOTAL
FROM
(select A,B, 
 months_between(trunc(start_Dt, 'MM'), trunc(sysdate,'MM' )  ) as month_offset,
  qty from total_Table
 where trunc(start_Dt) >= trunc(sysdate) - (to_number(to_char(sysdate,'DD')) - 1)
) 
WHERE month_offset IN (1,2,3,4)
  Group by A, B;
```

Cheers!!